# how to execute more than one command gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, kill, gnome-terminal

I have a script which is running some of (more than 15) applications like:

```
cd mypath
sleep 1
gnome-terminal -t App1 --tab -e "./App1" 
sleep 1
gnome-terminal -t App2 --tab -e "./App2" 
..
..
sleep 1
gnome-terminal -t App15 --tab -e "./App15"
```

As you can notice this will start apps in 15 different terminals.

Now what happens is when I kill any `./AppX` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, for any reason, it terminates the program as well as exits that terminal.

What I want is when I press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it should only terminates the `./AppX`, but terminal still remain open, that is beacause when I want to start that `AppX` again I should press only Up Arrow key and Enter.

**EDIT::**
**Got the Answer** :: [see the accepted answer from askubuntu.com.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)

**Another question is** : How do I execute more than one command like following:

```
gnome-terminal -e "sleep 1; AppX"
```

which is NOT working, I tried various other methods (&, &&, |) but all failed.

Comment: No, its still terminating the terminal, when I press `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: Do you want to execute each command in different tab? or more than one command in single tab?

Comment: each command in different tab

Answer (score 1):

The following command will open new terminal with 15 tabs in multi-gnome-terminal:

```
cd mypath
multi-gnome-terminal \
  --add-tab -tname App1 --tcommand "./App1" \
  --add-tab -tname App2 --tcommand "./App2" \
  ...
  --add-tab -tname App15 --tcommand "./App15" \
```

If you really need those sleeps, you can incorporate them:

```
cd mypath
multi-gnome-terminal \
  --add-tab -tname App1 --tcommand "sleep 1; ./App1" \
  --add-tab -tname App2 --tcommand "sleep 2; ./App2" \
  ...
  --add-tab -tname App15 --tcommand "sleep 15; ./App15" \
```

And if you need to dynamically change count/list of commands you are about to launch, you can use the following:

```
cd mypath
cmd=(multi-gnome-terminal)
cmd=("${cmd[@]}" --add-tab -tname App1 --tcommand "sleep 1; ./App1")
cmd=("${cmd[@]}" --add-tab -tname App2 --tcommand "sleep 2; ./App2")
  ...
cmd=("${cmd[@]}" --add-tab -tname App15 --tcommand "sleep 15; ./App15")
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not working as per my requirements.